# how to install boost 1.40 on Ubuntu 10.04?

Tags: ubuntu, boost

I have downloaded the file from http://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost/1.40.0/boost_1_40_0.tar.gz/download

However, I don't know how to install it after downloading the file.

Comment: 1.40 is ancient, why not install a newer version?

Comment: I want to install a tool, and it can be used on boost 1.40 successfully. I am not sure whether it can work on higher version

Answer (score 0):

Follow these instructions in order to properly setup Boost C++:
[Link to "Getting started" manual](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html).

Be aware that the version you downloaded is not the latest one. Boost C++ reached version 1.50 already.

Comment: I installed the boost follow the instructions,however, when I install rose, using "../rose-0.9.5a-14269/configure --prefix=‘pwd../rose‘ -with-CXX_DEBUG=-g1
--with-C_DEBUG=-g1 --with-CXX_WARNINGS=-Wall --without-java
--build=x86_64-pc-linux --with-boost=/usr/
--with-boost-libdir=/usr/lib64/ --with-haskell=no", there is error msg says "Boost libraries (version 1.36 or higher) must be specified on the configure line (using the --with-boost=<path> option) and the boost libraries must be in your LD_LIBRARY_PATH."  what's the problem?

Comment: Did you set the environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to contain the directory where boost was installed to?